# Transfer a variable from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, html

I derived the data from database and stored like that in php

```
<tr>
<td><a href=SMSindex.php?tp_no=$row[tel] >
     <img src=images/phone.png width=30 height=30 >
    </a>
</td>
<td>".$row["name"]."</td> </tr>
```

when I click the phone.png image, the SMSindex.php want to echo they phone number without show in the URL.(if is just use $_GET[tel] get the answer but same time i can see in the same phone no in url also.)

(the problem solved by Mr.Sulthan Allaudeen)

Comment: No this is the proper way, after some minor fixes. `{$row['tel']}` since it is being used inside a string

Comment: but we can see the phone number in URL. i no need to show

Comment: Then store it in a session variable and access on the other page

Comment: http://localhost:88/web/SMSindex.php?tp_no={%27tel:94771122336%27} the URL look like this. so this method is not good isn't ?

Comment: If you have the above url that you have, then you should have `$_GET['tp_no']`

Comment: i used session also but the table work in WHILE loop. so last phone no only echo

Comment: @shanthini You wan to make available the phone number globally ?

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "
<tr>
<td> <a href=SMSindex.php?tp_no=$row[tel] > <img src=images/phone.png width=30 height=30 > </a>
</td>
<td>".$row["name"]."</td>
<td>".$row["district"]."</td>           
<td>".$row["area"]."</td>
<td>".$row["org_manu"]."</td>
</tr>";}

Comment: Can you update the code in your question or create a http://www.eval.in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to achieve this.

You have a syntax error here.

```
<td>".$row["name"]."</td> </tr>
```

It shall be fixed by

```
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td> </tr>
```

[ Or the way Hanky 웃 Panky suggested ]

You can have it in your session by

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name']
?>
```

And retrieve it on another page by

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

**Update :**

If you have this in your url and you want to have your `tp_no` globally available then you should replace the `$row['name']` by `$_GET['tp_no']`

```
http://localhost:88/web/SMSindex.php?tp_no={%27tel:94771122336%27}
```

You should get the tp_no by

```
$_GET['tp_no']
```

But I don't know the reason you wrap around `{}`

**Update :**

As you don't want to see the url in the page.

Here's a tiny workaround to overcome it.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['tp_no'])) 
{
$_SESSION['tp_no'] = $_GET['tp_no'];
unset($_GET['tp_no']);
$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].http_build_query($_GET);
header("Refresh:0; url=".$url);
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['tp_no'])) 
{
echo $_SESSION['tp_no'];
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}
else
{
    echo "Direct / Illegal Access not allowed";
}
?>
```

**An Explained Version**

```
<?php
session_start();    #Starting the Session
if (isset($_GET['tp_no']))  #Checking whether we have $_GET value from the url 
{
$_SESSION['tp_no'] = $_GET['tp_no']; # We are assiging the tp_no to session
unset($_GET['tp_no']); #Here we are unsetting the value that we get from url
$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].http_build_query($_GET); #Here we are removing gettgint the url and removing the tp_no from it 
header("Refresh:0; url=".$url); #Now we are redirecting/refreshing the page with tp_no - As you said you need it :)
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['tp_no']))  
#Here is the else if condition once we refresh the page we won't have $_GET so the it will come inside this loop
{
echo $_SESSION['tp_no']; #Displaying the value that is from the session
session_unset();     #Unsetting the session value for secure
session_destroy();   #Destroying the entire session value for secure
}
else
{
#The compiler will come to this part if both session or url is not set, So this is illegal area
    echo "Direct / Illegal Access not allowed";  
#There might be some hackers/genius persons who will try to access directly this page, to avoid them we are showing them the above warning message
}
?>
```

Comment: there is no syntax error in my coding to derive phone number or name, and also it work properly. whenever i add the name and phone number into database, the image want to create for the name   and when i click the image, another page want to echo that number without show the number in url.  That is my requirement.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have in http:://www.eval.in ? It would be easy to understand

Comment: i send it to your email. (similar coding)

Comment: Sure, Will check it :)

Comment: Something like this ? http://sysaxiom.com/test/shanthini/new.php ?

Comment: yes i need like that  out put